# Why is the multi-variable function $f(x,y)=\exp(-1/(x^2+y^2))$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I don't understand this problem:

> Show that the function $f: \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $$f(x,y)=\exp\left\{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}\right\}$$ for $(x,y)≠(0,0)$ and  $f(0,0)=0$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: You want to show that the limit of the function exists at (0, 0), and matches the given value.

Comment: @Sally Thank you! I will look at it.

Comment: @Kaynex Yes, but when I replace x and y for 0, I will get indeterminate didn't i?

Comment: @Tiasn: Yes, that's why $f(0, 0)$ is specially assigned the value $0$.  Your task is to demonstrate that this special assignment "makes sense": that in the (punctured) neighborhood of $(0, 0)$, $f$ is always in the vicinity of a single value, which happens to be $f(0, 0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}=0=f(0,0)$$
Note that: 
$$e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}$$
and as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$:  $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\rightarrow\infty$ and $\frac{1}{e^\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 2):

hint:use the inequality: $e^{-u} \leq \dfrac{1}{1+u}$ with $u = \dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: ok, this help me a lot! I was really lost with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\text{As }(x,y) & \to (0,0), \\[10pt]
x^2+y^2 & \downarrow 0 \\[6pt]
\frac 1 {x^2+y^2} & \uparrow \infty \\[10pt]
\frac {-1} {x^2+y^2} & \downarrow -\infty \\[10pt]
\exp\left(\frac {-1} {x^2+y^2}\right) & \downarrow 0 \\[6pt]
\end{align}